# Extract the different props between array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

What would be the most efficient way of achiveing the following:

```js
let oldArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 5}]
let newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 6}]
let result = extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray,newArray, 'id') // [{id: "12", units: 6}]
```

And

```js
let oldArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 5}]
let newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 35, units: 6}]
let result = extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray,newArray, "id") // [{id: "12", salePrice: 35, units: 6}]
```

And

```js
let oldArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 5}]
let newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 6}]
let result = extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray,newArray, "product") // [{product: "6", units:6}]
```

And

```js
let oldArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 5}]
let newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 5}]
let result = extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray,newArray, "id") // []
```

The `extractArrayObjectDifference` function should create an array with objects containing "id" or any other prop supplied as 3rd argument and each prop that has been modified from objects in the original array.

I have tried the following but I can't seem to make it work. I used lodash

```
import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty'
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual'
import isObject from 'lodash/isObject'
function difference(object, base) {
    return transform(object, (result: any, value, key) => {
        if (!isEqual(value, base[key])) {
            result[key] = (isObject(value) && isObject(base[key])) ? difference(value, base[key]) : value;
        }
    });
}

function extractArrayObjectDifference(oldVal, newVal, key) {
    let out = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= newVal.length; i++) {
        let result = difference(newVal[i], oldVal[i])
        if (!isEmpty(result)) {
            result[key] = newVal[key]
            out.push(result)
        }
    }
    return out
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with `Object.entries(newArray[i]).filter(...)` The filter function should return the `id` property and any properties that have different values from `oldArray[i]`.

Comment: I am sorry for not posting my solution that I failed to make work. I am not using stack overflow as a free coding service.

Comment: Isn't `difference()` supposed to take 3 arguments?

Comment: Will the corresponding elements always be at the same index in both arrays?

Comment: yes, they will be at the same index.  have renamed the function, for sake of simplicity. I have updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.entries()` to loop over the properties of the old and new objects. Then use `.filter()` to select just the properties to keep, which are the ones that are different between the two objects, as well as the `id` property. Finally, put that back to gether as a new object.

When looping over the arrays, you can filter the results to remove the objects that only have one property. That will always just be the `id` property, so it means all the other properties were the same and you don't want this in the result.

```js
function difference(oldObj, newObj, keyToKeep) {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(newObj).filter(([key, val]) =>
      key == keyToKeep || val != oldObj[key]
    )
  );
}

function extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray, newArray, key) {
  return oldArray.map((el, i) => difference(el, newArray[i], key))
    .filter(obj => Object.keys(obj).length > 1);
}

let oldArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 5}]

let newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 6}]
console.log(extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray, newArray, 'id')) // [{id: "12", units: 6}]

newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 35, units: 6}]
console.log(extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray, newArray, "id")) // [{id: "12", salePrice: 35, units: 6}]

newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 6}]
console.log(extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray, newArray, "product")) // [{product: "6", units:6}]

newArray = [{id: "12", product: "6", price: 30, salePrice: 33, units: 5}]
console.log(extractArrayObjectDifference(oldArray, newArray, "id")) // []
```